# How to acces textfield values inside tableview cell when using TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, tableview

I have integrated TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView to handle next responder of textfields. How can i access textfield values as i cannot assign textfield delegates.

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField.tag == UserDetails.Name.rawValue{
            name = textField.text!
            print(name)
        }
        else if textField.tag == UserDetails.Mobile.rawValue{
            mobile = textField.text!
            print(mobile)
        }
        else if textField.tag == UserDetails.Qualification.rawValue{
            qualification = textField.text!
            print(qualification)
        }
        else if textField.tag == UserDetails.Area.rawValue{
            area = textField.text!
            print(area)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Share the code what you have worked on so far

Comment: @Nitish i have added the code for cellforrow

Comment: Did you try setting focusNextTextField property for the TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView as true ?

Comment: No i had not set.

Comment: Try that and let us know the results

Comment: @Nitish i tried setting tblProfile.focusNextTextField() but textfield delegates are not getting called

Comment: See if this is useful : https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding/issues/225

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best way, but it should work :

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    var indexPath: IndexPath?
    if (textField.superview?.superview is YourCell) {
        let cell = textField.superview?.superview as? UITableViewCell
        indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
    }
    let indexPathNextRow = IndexPath(row: indexPath?.row + 1, section: indexPath?.section ?? 0)
    let cellNextRow = (tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPathNextRow) as? YourCell) as? YourCell
    let tag = Int(indexPathNextRow.row)
    let textFieldNextRow = cellNextRow?.contentView.viewWithTag(tag) as? UITextField
    textFieldNextRow?.becomeFirstResponder()
    print("last text field---------->\(Int(textField.tag))")
    return true
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    textValues[textField.tag] = textField.text ?? ""
}
```

Don't forget to set tag for cell's `UITextField`

Comment: what is RegisterCell?

Comment: That is the cell I have used in my code. Replace it with your custom cell

Comment: textValues is a global array having text of all UITextField's

Comment: Perfect. Happy coding